# using snap svg, how can I calculate the whole paths of an svg file in pixels?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to find the sum of the length of all paths for an svg paths.
And I have the following( the paths are put in an array):

```
...
    var totalPxl=0;
      for (var i=0; i < this.pathArray.length; i++){
        var totalPxl = this.pathArray[i].getTotalLength();

        console.log(totalPxl);
      }
```

This lists all the paths length individually, How can I add them up?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var totalPxl = this.pathArray[i].getTotalLength();` by

```
totalPxl += this.pathArray[i].getTotalLength();
```

If you just want to print the total, move the console.log statement outside and below the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert. That works perfect. it lists all the paths added to the previous one. How can I get only the last number which is the sum of all the paths?